# Budgie head feathers are clumping, looks like he has a shiny wet coating then it dries

Tags: health, budgerigar

I have a four year old budgie who is in good health and gets lots of exercise flying about the house. He is very tame and of a good nature. He molts frequently.
His head feathers from the top above his eyes back about a half inch get wet from some kind of clear secretion and when it dries the feathers clump. If I can get him to take a bath and get his head wet it will clear up but it is reoccurring and he rubs his head on his perch so I know it bothers him.

Comment: Welcome to Pets.SE! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute but shows you how this site works. Sorry for being nitpicky, but Pets.SE is a Q&A site, meaning every post must ask a question. Your post contains valuable information, but no question. Could you please [edit] your post and ask one specific question, like what could have caused this clumping or how to avoid it?